# Not able to see Question and Answer field on Knowledge object

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I am working on Developer org and need to create a knowledge article. But I am unable to see Question and Answer fields in the page layout.
I checked all the settings from other org where it is available.

Please guide, how can it be available in my org?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have enabled the `Knowledge User` in your user settings. Also, ensure required permissions are set-up for your profile (if you are the admin on your dev org, then it would be already done) and configure knowledge settings in the set up (refer to this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/knowledge_essentials/knowledge_essentials_enable))

[image]